# I need sql IN query for multiple values in single column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a SQL `IN` query where in the below table

```
ID    NAME      VALUES
1    Germany   0004;0009;0014;0045;0064
2    Italy     0007;0014;0020;0041;0064
3    France    0014;0020;0015;0038;0074;0064;0066
```

I have an input parameter like `(0014,0020,0064)` currently I am using like below

```
select * 
from table_name 
where VALUES like '%0014%' 
   or VALUES like '%0020%' 
   or VALUES like '%0064%'
```

If I have 3 or 4 input parameters it is ok for me but the input parameters will be more than 50 in that case I need to avoid like query. Is there any options using IN query or another query to use it?

Comment: You should be normalizing your table.

Comment: Can you please show how `parameters` are coming ..

Comment: What about JOIN AND LIKE . .

Comment: What kind of database you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Try to write a `stored procedure`, which will be taking `select IN` clause values as its parameters and iterating through entire column values and return `out` parameters as result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a string splitter for this. Here is one using XML:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split
(
   @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT Item = y.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
      FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
          + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
          + '</i>').query('.')
      ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
   );
```

Here now is your final query:

```
DECLARE @param VARCHAR(MAX) = '0014,0020,0064'

SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM tbl t
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(t.[VALUES], ';') s
WHERE
    s.Item IN(SELECT Item FROM dbo.Split(@param, ','))
```

Comment: i tried this query but my column datatype is text i tried with CONVERT(varchar, VALUES) it shows "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'."

Comment: DECLARE @param VARCHAR(MAX) = '0014,0020,0064'
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM PASSWORD_RULES t
CROSS APPLY dbo.Split(t.CONVERT(VARCHAR, POPULATION_LIST), ';') s
WHERE
    s.Item IN(SELECT Item FROM dbo.Split(@param, ','))

Comment: It should be `(CONVERT(VARCHAR, t.POPULATION_LIST)`, you put the table alias before the column. Although, why the need to convert to `VARCHAR`. Isn't your column already a `VARCHAR`?

Comment: Okay then, make sure you convert to `VARCHAR(MAX)`. FYI, `text` is being deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

Your query could be re-written as:

```
select * from table_name where VALUES IN ('0014', '0020', '0064')
```

Note that you can't use LIKE and IN together. So as Felix said, you need to normalise your table to get this working.

Comment: No, this won't work, as the value are in `string`, in case of `IN('0014')`, it will gona search for column having value '0014' and not for `string` containing '0014'

Comment: Well, that is the problem isn't it. NORMALISE your table.

Comment: Normalise may not work, as user might not be knowing how much columns are required (values may be dynamic).

Comment: for normalization its not required to know how much column required , there will be one more table with This table's `id` will be foreign key and one column for `value` will be there.As many entry for Value will be there that many rows will be in the new table for that particular id .

Comment: The whole point of normalisation is to allow for an unknown number of values. As the table is currently setup, it can only accommodate a handful of values before this column fills up. Contrast to a properly normalised table, with a new row for each value you want to represent, and you can store thousands of these rows with no problem. It's also easier to query. As long as you avoid normalisation, you'll have to use inefficient sql to get around it.